# Continuous compound Poisson and Binomial

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Suppose a random vector $X$ that is distributed:

$X|N \sim \text{MN}(N,p_1,p_2...p_J)$

$N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$

What is the continuous analog of each distribution and the continuous marginal distribution of $X$?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous analogue"? The poisson distribution can be considered the limit of the binomial distribution as $p \to 0$, with $\lambda = N p$ fixed. In any case, for a given distribution, there can be multiple ways to take limits and get similar distributions. I think this is an interesting question which I would like to know the canonical answer to, if one exists, but for the reason above I doubt one exists.